# How can I populate an ExpandableListView child views through Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expandablelistview

I want to populate my expandable list view with the values from Firebase database. I am able to add data to views statically but through Firebase not.

This is my code for that:

```
public class ExpandableListitems {
public List<String> food;

public HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
    final HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();



    //getting fooditems from database
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabasefighter = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReferencefighter = firebaseDatabasefighter.getReference("food").child("food_details");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListenerfighter = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                food = new ArrayList<String>();
                String value = String.valueOf(ds.getValue());


                food.add(value);

                Log.i("vipan",value);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseReferencefighter.addValueEventListener(valueEventListenerfighter);


    food.add("milk");
    food.add("dahi");
    food.add("paratha");
    food.add("aaloo");


   expandableListDetail.put("FoodItems", food);
    return expandableListDetail;
```

And my database looks like this:

```
  food
```

food_details: 
"2% Fat Milk"

i want to add this **food_details** value into the *listview's view* but unable so far.How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot simply return the `expandableListDetail HashMap<String, List<String>>` which contains a list of strings that is coming from the database as a result of a method because this list will always be `empty` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to return that result, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the `food` list only inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Hey @Alex Mamo i tried the solution from your post . but i m getting an println  needs a message error.

Comment: You need to make sure you pass to the `println()` method a string that is not `null`.

Comment: can you please post the answer  with code to help me out here because i am not getting what i am doing wrong. in database i have more than one value but my app is till crashing

Comment: This `println()` error sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are passing null to that method but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.